# Dojo Custom widget not rendering inside content pane

Tags: dojo, widget, nested

I have a custom widget:

```
 define([
         ......],

 function (...){

 return decalre('ownerWidget', [....],{

 templateString: template,

 postCreate: function () {

  this.inherited(arguments);

  var data ={

     identifier:'id',
     label: 'id',
     items: [{
          id:'28'
          owner: 'Fred',
          attendingId: '1',
          numberOfVisits: '3',
          vetCostsThisYear: '4',
          complaints: '0',
          children[{
              id : '29',
              pet:'Mario',
              numberOfVisits: '3',
              vetCostsThisYear: '4',
              complaints: '0'

           }]

   }]
};

var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data:data});
var model = new ForestStoreModel({store : store, childrenAttrs:    ['children']});

var layout = [
{name: 'Owner', field:'owner', width: '40%'},
{name: 'Pet', field: 'pet', width: '40%'},
{name: 'Attending Id', field:'attendingId', width: '5%'},
{name: 'Visits', field: 'numberOfVisits', width: '5%'}];

var gridTree = new LazyTreeGrid({
    treeModel: model, 
    structure: layout
}, document.createElement('div'));


 this.gridTreeNode.appendChild(gridTree.domNode);
 }
 });

 });
```

the template for this:

```
 <div data-dojo-attach-point="gridTreeNode" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
```

the widget is then declared in another widgets template like so:

```
<div class="grid" data-dojo-attach-point="byOwner" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"></div>
```

the javascript for the above declaration:

```
 this.byOwner.set('title', "Owner");
 this.byOwner.set('content', "ownerWidget");
```

I get a grey background and the tab appears with the correct title but the grid does not seem to be rendering, i can see there is a dom tree for the grid but i am just not seeing the grid on the page.

I am not sure what I am missing here, there are no errors whatsoever or warnings.

Dojo version 1.10.0

Comment: At first I can say : you have a typo `decalre`, you forget to call `gridTree.startup()`... There is probably more than that...

Comment: the declare was a typo indeed, i accidently deleted it and typos when i retyped it into the question, my understanding of dojo is that if you declaratively declare a widget then startup is handled by the parser ?

Comment: `startup` of components created by the parser are automatically executed (like when using declarative syntax). However in your case you programmatically created `gridTree` so you need to manually call `startup`

Comment: ahh i see, so if the widget is created programatically it does not matter if i declare an instance declaratively i still need to call startup within my widget ?

Comment: in your case `ownerWidget` will be started automatically but not it's child widget

Comment: Ok, i can see now that it is rendering a dom structure for the grid, width and height of some of the inner dom nodes are 0, after manually changing these i could see the grid, looks like this is now a css issue.

Comment: This is sill a startup issue, See my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a startup issue.
You need to manually start the component at the right moment (otherwise calculation goes wrong).
Calling `placeAt` method will handle that for you (see last line) :

```js
define([
    /*......*/
],

function( /*...*/ ) {

    return declare('ownerWidget', [ /*....*/ ], {

        templateString: template,

        postCreate: function() {

            this.inherited(arguments);

            var data = {

                identifier: 'id',
                label: 'id',
                items: [{
                    id: '28'
                    owner: 'Fred',
                    attendingId: '1',
                    numberOfVisits: '3',
                    vetCostsThisYear: '4',
                    complaints: '0',
                    children[{
                        id: '29',
                        pet: 'Mario',
                        numberOfVisits: '3',
                        vetCostsThisYear: '4',
                        complaints: '0'

                    }]

                }]
            };

            var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({
                data: data
            });
            var model = new ForestStoreModel({
                store: store,
                childrenAttrs: ['children']
            });

            var layout = [{
                name: 'Owner',
                field: 'owner',
                width: '40%'
            }, {
                name: 'Pet',
                field: 'pet',
                width: '40%'
            }, {
                name: 'Attending Id',
                field: 'attendingId',
                width: '5%'
            }, {
                name: 'Visits',
                field: 'numberOfVisits',
                width: '5%'
            }];

            var gridTree = new LazyTreeGrid({
                treeModel: model,
                structure: layout
            }, document.createElement('div'));

            gridTree.placeAt(this.gridTreeNode, 'last');
        }
    });

});
```